# Merge dll file Into EXE C# (.Net 6)

Tags: c#

Didn't find any way to merge dll with C# app .Net 6

The app will not lunch without 2 dll files GunaUI.dll , and another one

Tried Fody/Costura.  It made a 8mb dll file. I won't any dlls

---

If nothing will work on .Net 6 How can I go to older version without losing my work?

Comment: So why don't you just ship the required DLLs with your app?

Comment: @KlausGütter I want a single file. I want to share exe not zip (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it !

By just publishing the file with this settings

[image: Publish Settings]